Lightroom "breaks" randomly
I don't really know how I can effectively describe my problem, but as I understand it more I will update this post.
My Adobe Lightroom v. 7.5, updated yesterday, sometimes "breaks". Several functions stop working properly, such as guided upright or AI powered object removal. Also, after lightroom "breaks" and I switch to the masks tab, the app automatically applies the "detect people" mask, fails to detect anyone, and all the other buttons on the masks tab become unaccessible. It all goes back to normal after I restart lightroom.
These are all minor annoyances, but it would still be great if someone could recommend a way to permanently prevent this. If/when I manage to be able to reproduce these bugs consistently I might edit in some screenshots as well. Thanks to everyone in advance.

Are you sure about the version? The current LR version is 13.5

That's Lightroom Classic. I am using regular Lightroom.

No clue why this is happening, but a suggestion to narrow down your search: can you start a new catalog (is that a thing in regular LR?) and see if the issues still occur?
